# what's the difference between @using and @namespace directives?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm new to asp.net razor page, sorry if my question sounds dumb.

It seems to me that both  `@using` and `@namespace` do the same thing which allows you don't use namespace-qualified full name? so `@using` and `@namespace` are interchangeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they don't do the same thing.

From https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/files/viewimports:

The `@namespace` directive specifies the root namespace to be used by pages (and their models). By convention, it is composed from a dot-separated path to the Razor Page location with the name of the application provided as the "root". Having the `@namespace` declaration in the *ViewImports* file saves you having to fully qualify the model names in the `@model` directive of individual pages.

You can only have one `@namespace` directive per *ViewImports* file. Adding multiple `@namespace` directives to the same file will result in Build errors.

You can add further `@using` directives to bring additional namespaces into scope:

```
@using MyApplication
@using MyApplication.Models
@using MyApplication.Services
@namespace MyApplication.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Comment: @Mikr Bring thanks for your answer, but still confused. In the example above, I can also use `@using MyApplication.Pages`, can't I?

Comment: Yes, you can but you don't need to. The pages are already in that namespace so you don't need to use `@using` in order to avoid having to use the fully qualified namespace in e.g. `@model` directives. But you can if you want to.

Comment: if `@namespace MyApplication.Pages`  can be replaced by `@using MyApplication.Pages`, then aren't these two things the same?

Comment: No. They don't do the same thing. The `@namespace` directive _sets_ the namespace for the content pages. The `@using` directive doesn't do that. It enables a shorthand way to refer to classes etc in other namespaces.

Comment: sorry to bother you again. Just want to confirmthat do yo mean Razor page can have its own namespace? I always thought only a class file(.cs) can have namespace, so `.cshtml` can also have namespace? but isn't that the code behind file of a razor page already have a namespace, for example, `index.cshtml.cs` can define its own space, and it looks like `@namespace` is used to set the namespace of `index.cshtml` so that it match its code behind file `index.cshtml.cs` 's namespace?

Comment: The view file and the code behind must be in the same namespace.